# MSBuild 4.0 Regex parsing

Tags: regex, parsing, msbuild

I have heard that MSBuild 4.0 has increased Regex parsing support. However, I am unable to find any detailed documentation/links/material on this. Can anyone give a brief description of the new features and/or possibly give pointers to more material?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah you would be able to perform regex using property functions, but still Regex is not a first class citizen :( Maybe next version.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have heard wrong. I haven't heard of this, and the MSBuild team has been communicating changes to me.